# Why this C++ assignment statement is illegal?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

My code is just like this:

```
void main(){
    char test[]  = "aaa";
    char* test2  ;
    *test2 = * test;
    Permutation(test);
    system("pause");

}
```

this code can run properly.But when I change it to:

```
void main(){
    char* test  = "aaa";
    char* test2  ;
    *test2 = * test;

}
```

vs 2012  reports an error. I actually know the difference when delcaring a string between "char * []" way and "char a[]" way.But I don't know how this error occrurs.
Any one can help me ?

Comment: There's hundreds of duplicates of this.

Comment: You're dereferencing an uninitialised pointer.

Comment: Both pieces of code have undefined behavior. The first one gets unlucky and does not crash, while the second one crashes.

Comment: `int main`, not `void main`.

Comment: @simple who cares if he uses msvc anyways. once he switchs platforms he will learn soon enough (not that it is a vast afford to refactor it)

Answer (score 4):

> I don't know how this error occrurs

You never initialise `test2` to point to anything, so dereferencing this invalid pointer with `*test2` gives undefined behaviour. This may crash the program, or corrupt some random memory location, or do anything else.

> Any one can help me ?

If you just want to copy the first character, then use a character rather than a pointer.

```
char test2 = *test;
```

If you want a copy of the whole string, your best bet is to use `std::string`; messing around with pointers is usually much more trouble than it's worth.

```
std::string test = "aaa";
std::string test2 = test;
```

If you really want to faff around with C-style character arrays for some reason, then you'll need to allocate a large enough array and copy the characters into it (perhaps with `memcpy` or `str(n)cpy`). I won't give an example, since I don't want to encourage this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

for both codes, you assign `*test2= *test;` it results the first code crushes; and the second code, only the first 'a' is being assigned to `test2`. If you want to assign the whole "aaa", you should do `test2= test;` because `*test` is only pointed to the first value 'a'.